# Is there any way to implement debugShowMaterialGrid for CupertinoApp?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is there any way to implement `debugShowMaterialGrid` and `themeMode` for CupertinoApp?

How efficient is wrapping a MaterialApp around it to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `CupertinoApp` widget hasn't `debugShowMaterialGrid` property but in non-material apps, u can wrap your widget with `GridPaper` and it shows the grid for you

> In non-Material applications, you can achieve a similar effect by using a GridPaper widget directly.

and for `themeMode` you can use this property in your `CupertinoApp`

```
  theme: CupertinoThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark // or Brightness.light
  ),
```